# Missing required parameters for [Route: about]

Tags: laravel

I installed `cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable` package.

I have an issue with the URLs i.e., with the hrefs and slug.

menu.blade.php

```
<a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('about') }}">
```

web.php

```
Route::get('content/{contentSlug}', 'PageController@content')->name('about');
```

RouteServiceProvider.php

```
    Route::bind('contentSlug', function ($value) {
        return Page::whereSlug($value)->firstOrFail();
    });
```

I get this error

> Illuminate\Routing\Exceptions\UrlGenerationException
> Missing required parameters for [Route: about] [URI: en/content/{contentSlug}]. (

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you don't pass {contentSlug} value in route.

```
<a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('about',['contentSlug' =>'Hello']) }}">
```

If you want to make route with optional parameter then use ? .{contentSlug?}